# Hierarchy Date in Power BI

Tags: date, charts, powerbi, hierarchy, linechart

Hello Power BI :)

My line chart is not showing hierarchy date as I want. the "Expand down level in the hierarchy" is not working as expected.

I want to see the X Axis by: Month, Quarter, Year as below:

[image]

But all I can get is the below:

[image]

I want to see lines instead of these dots as well.

How to fix that, what's wrong that im doing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I guess right- You are getting single Dot as you have data for the year 2020 only. Now you have option of drill down on right top of your line chart as shown in the below image. You can go to Year, Quarter, Month, Day using those options.

[image]

Comment: This is the issue, the drill down is not giving me what's expected. Once I click on it, nothing changes.

Comment: Then check your Date hierarchy properly set or not.