# My line chart keeps showing only a point(i.e. summation) even after drilling it down to months

Tags: date, powerbi, visualization, linechart, drilldown

[This is the result I keep on getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqFvo.png)   [This is 1 of 3 of the combined data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPICa.png) I am new to Power BI, and I have been trying to create a line chart of my budget and the actual amount spent for the fiscal year. But I keep on getting just 2 dots showing the summation for the fiscal year. I would love it to show a line chart showing the trend throughout the year. I drilled the chart down to months but it keeps on showing only a dot with the total amount spent for the fiscal year. I have watched so many videos on this and followed through,[Here's the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4qka.png) but I keep on getting the result I show earlier. Any ideas on how to change this? Would be grateful.

Comment: Show your sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have added the two requested information. Would be grateful for any assistance

Comment: My problem is, why does it keep generating just 3 dots instead of a trend line. I even drilled down to months yet no difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892471/hierarchy-date-in-power-bi?rq=2
Here's the exact same problem. I did not find the answer I was looking for

Comment: In your sample data, I can see only your Actual amount. Where from Forecast/Budget coming?